# FFMPEG : Merging Two Audio Files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using following command to merge two audio file, which works fine.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=tag.wav:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[tag]; [0][tag]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2" tag-out.mp3
```

But what I really need to do is repeat and delay 10 seconds the audio tag depending on the main song length. Also, the main song audio volume lowers while the audio tag plays.

Any ideas/help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This command already repeats the tag. What does delay 10 seconds mean - - the initial start time of the tag?

Comment: Yes, I want to play tag file after each 10 seconds like main audio file length is 50 seconds then tag file should be merge only 5 time on every 10 seconds of position.

Comment: @Gyan looking for your help --  thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wish to alter effective length of the tag, skip the amovie looping and use the aloop filter after padding the audio to 10s.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=tag.wav,asetpts=N/SR/TB,apad=whole_dur=10,aloop=-1:1M:0[tag]; [0][tag]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2" -vn tag-out.mp3
```

Comment: mentioned command is not working, Please check the following execution response.


r   Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26
[mp3 @ 0x1b59ee0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[Parsed_apad_2 @ 0x1b73760] Option 'whole_dur' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1b4b460] Error initializing filter 'apad' with args 'whole_dur=10'
Error configuring filters.
root@bea [/home/petarandzic/public_html/media]#

Comment: You'll need a recent static git/snapshot build.

Comment: Thanks for your response, please check this this snapshot https://beatscentral.co/media/ffmpeg.png

Comment: That's version 2.6.8. Get a git build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Thank you so much, provided command working fine as per my expectation but there is showing some error. can you please check this attached screen shot https://beatscentral.co/media/ffmpeg-3.png 

many thanks for your help.

Comment: Those errors in red just mean that some ID3 tag in the MP3 is malformed. Doesn't affect the audio.